# Is this code snippet a secure way of creating a user?

Tags: php, security, pdo, prepare

If i allow a user to choose his username with any digit(abcABC-_.,!"§%§& etc..)

and i do this with the POST:

```
$username = trim($_POST['username']);
$username = stripslashes($username);
$username = htmlentities($username);
$username = htmlspecialchars($username);
```

and before inserting in database use i use prepared statement with PDO:

```
try
{
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO user (username)
                                    VALUES (?)");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $value1);

    $value1 = $username;
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $exception)
{
    // catch error-msg
}
```

Is this 100% secure or do i have to add some more things? Greetings and thanks!!

Comment: Get rid of the first code block entirely. It'll destroy user names for no good reason. Instead, apply `htmlspecialchars()` when *outputting* the user name in a HTML context

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use **filter_var** or **filter_input** instead of doing the execution of all those functions in first block.

<kbd>[filter_var](http://php.net/filter_var)</kbd> or <kbd>[filter_input](http://php.net/filter_input)</kbd>

### Example

```
$username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

**Sanitize filters** — https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Comment: Prepared statements alone are sufficient.